# Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 288x512 dp

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, layout, admob

I have been trying to use admob for about 4 hours now, and am really stuck right now. I am getting:

```
 Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 288x512 dp.
```

But, I think there is enough space. After all, the ad shows up in the design view of the layout. Can you please help me find out what is wrong? I have looked at the other 10 - 20 stack overflow pages, but it didn't help.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:background="#000000"

    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text_container"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="58dp">


        <TextView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="20:00"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:textColor="#fbfafa"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"

            android:id="@+id/timetext" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:columnCount="4"
            android:rowCount="4">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="0">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:id="@+id/Blue"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Red"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Red"
                    android:background="@drawable/bluesquare"
                    android:onClick="onClick"/>
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="1">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:id="@+id/Red"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                    android:background="@drawable/redsquare"
                    android:onClick="onClick"/>
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout3"
                android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="0">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:id="@+id/Green"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/greensquare"
                    android:onClick="onClick"/>
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/frameLayout3"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout4"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="1">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:id="@+id/Purple"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Green"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/purplesquare"
                    android:onClick="onClick"/>
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                android:id="@+id/framelayout5"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="3">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:id="@+id/Brown"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                    android:background="@drawable/brownsquare"
                    android:onClick="onClick"/>
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout6"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="3">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:id="@+id/Pink"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                    android:background="@drawable/pinksquare"
                    android:onClick="onClick"/>
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                android:id="@+id/framelayout7"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="3">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:id="@+id/Yellow"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                    android:background="@drawable/yellowsquare"
                    android:onClick="onClick"/>
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                android:id="@+id/framelayout8"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="0">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:id="@+id/Peach"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                    android:background="@drawable/peachsquare"
                    android:onClick="onClick"/>
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                android:id="@+id/framelayout9"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="1">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:id="@+id/Grey"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                    android:background="@drawable/greysquare"
                    android:onClick="onClick"/>
            </FrameLayout>

        </GridLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Why is there not enough space?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

i solved my issue by put following code in to Manifest.xml file under

```
<activity
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Left and right padding of your main layout creating problem

remove

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

from your main layout